# I want to retrieve Google Calendar's events, reminders and Goals info

Tags: java, spring

I have accessed all events configured in Google Calendar using below information.

GET API: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/list

Authorization : "Bearar Token"

Host: [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com)

But didn't find similar kind API info to retrieve Reminders and Goals.

Can some one help me, how to get these info from Calendar (Google server).

Comment: Goals don't seem to be officially part of it. Reminders and notifications are properties of evens, or property of the calendar if event uses default reminder rules.

Comment: how we can differentiate for reminder or event ?

Comment: They are two entirely different entities. Reminder is something to remind user about an event.